# Bind native html5 dragstart event handler and access dataTransfer using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

**This is working:**

```
$(".my_dragging_class").each( makeDraggable($(this).get()[0]) );

var makeDraggable = function (el){
    el.draggable = 'true';
    el.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e){
                e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
                e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', 'test');
                console.log('dragstart');
                }, 
            false);
}
```

**This is NOT working:**

```
$(".my_dragging_class").makeDraggable();

$.fn.makeDraggable(){
    $(this).attr('draggable','true');
    $(this).bind('dragstart', function(e){
                e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
                e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', 'test');
                console.log('dragstart');
                }, 
            false);
}
```

**Error message:** I receive a *'e.dataTransfer is undefined'* for the line `e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';`. My Browser is FireFox 10.0.2

Is it possible to use dataTransfer with jQuery this way?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try:

```
$.fn.makeDraggable(){
    $(this).attr('draggable','true');
    $(this).bind('dragstart', function(e){
                e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
                e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', 'test');
                console.log('dragstart');
                }, 
            false);
}
```

The [jQuery event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)  does not have a `dataTransfer` property.

Comment: How compatible is this method? All you did was append "originalEvent", right? Thanks.

Comment: I am very new to jQuery, but when you add the false at the end of the bind function it prevents me from dragging. Removing the false and all works as expected.

Answer (score 6):

The [jQuery event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) does not have a dataTransfer property...
true, but one can try:

```
jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');
```

kr, zara

Comment: What exactly does it do? An explanation would make this answer more useful.

Comment: toscho -> Per: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/ - Certain events may have properties specific to them. Those can be accessed as properties of the event.originalEvent object. To make special properties available in all event objects, they can be added to the jQuery.event.props array. This is not recommended, since it adds overhead to every event delivered by jQuery.